# Pandas converting and combining object, integer columns to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, type-conversion, dtype

Suppose I have following data with data formats:

| date | time |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-04-21 | 610 |
| 2022-04-22 | 610 |
| 2022-04-22 | 1751 |

date: object

time: int32

I wish to combine date column and time column to make new column 'datetime' with datetime format like this:

| date | time | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-21 | 610 | 2022-04-21 6:10 |
| 2022-04-22 | 610 | 2022-04-22 7:01 |
| 2022-04-22 | 1751 | 2022-04-22 17:51 |

When I use following codes, I get errors as following:

1. Converting object to datetime

   df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%M-%d')

| date | time |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-21 00:04:00 | 610 |
| 2022-01-22 00:04:00 | 610 |
| 2022-01-22 00:04:00 | 1751 |

2. Converting int32 to datetime

   df_trade['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_trade['time'], format='%H:%M')

ValueError: time data '610' does not match format '%H:%M' (match)

I guess the last step must be easy with following code, but columns are not in the right format to combine.

```
df_trade['datetime'] = df_trade['date'].astype(str)+" "+df_trade['time'].astype(str)
```

How do I convert the object, int32 columns into datetime format without changing the contents?

Answer (score 2):

You are close, all your solution should be combined, only change few typos - for months need `%m` and for parse times need remove `:` - `%H%M`:

```
df_trade['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_trade['date'] +' '+ df_trade['time'].astype(str), 
                                      format='%Y-%m-%d %H%M')
print (df_trade)
         date  time            datetime
0  2022-04-21   610 2022-04-21 06:10:00
1  2022-04-22   610 2022-04-22 06:10:00
2  2022-04-22  1751 2022-04-22 17:51:00
```